# Huggingface pipeline error: IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

Anyone know why I get that error when I run the pipeline?

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline

modeltemp = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model=modeltemp, tokenizer=tokenizer)
unmasker("Hello I drive a red [MASK].")
```

If I directly have the pipeline take in bert-base-cased, everything works. But if I first load bert-base-cased using AutoModel, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You instantiated a wrong AutoModel class compared to the pipeline you declared.

The model is intended for Sequence classification, not fill-mask, so the responses of the model do not work correctly because the pipeline expects different output. That is the reason why you see dimension related problem.

## Solution

Move to a AutoModelForMaskedLM Model and your code will work correctly

```
from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline

modeltemp = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model=modeltemp, tokenizer=tokenizer)
unmasker("Hello I drive a red [MASK].")

>> [{'score': 0.18619821965694427,
  'token': 14013,
  'token_str': 'Ferrari',
  'sequence': 'Hello I drive a red Ferrari.'},
 {'score': 0.1289202719926834,
  'token': 13439,
  'token_str': 'BMW',
  'sequence': 'Hello I drive a red BMW.'},
 {'score': 0.0779753103852272,
  'token': 12110,
  'token_str': 'Honda',
  'sequence': 'Hello I drive a red Honda.'},
 {'score': 0.0691772997379303,
  'token': 21064,
  'token_str': 'Mustang',
  'sequence': 'Hello I drive a red Mustang.'},
 {'score': 0.055530842393636703,
  'token': 14062,
  'token_str': 'Harley',
  'sequence': 'Hello I drive a red Harley.'}]
```